# Entity with some known properties and some unknown at compile time

Tags: c#, dynamic, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I am new to C# and Entity Framework. I am creating a project to read all of the rows and columns from a SQL table. When a user connects to a database, a list of tables will be populated to choose from. Once a table is selected, I want to display all of the rows and all of the columns from the selected table in a data grid.

How can I use ef core (Blazor WASM actually) to read columns and rows from a table that has an unknown structure at build-time?

A dbcontext can be used to interact with the SQL database. That is easy enough. Creating a class with the columns in it as properties, then reading the rows from the table is easy enough with IQueryable.Entity. But what if you do not know what the table structure is at design-time? Is there a way to get an IQueryable for an unknown entity structure?

Can you create an entity (or class) using a list of strings that are the column names?

I re-worded the question in hopes that this makes more sense. It is hard to believe that this isn't a very common task.

Comment: One way would be fetching data as raw `DataTable` and displaying it on the UI, but I doubt you would like it

Comment: EF is not really the best tool for runtime-defined data models or data-models that change very frequently - I agree with @AndriyShevchenko that you should consider using raw `DataTable`. EF also doesn't support SQL Server table-valued parameters or custom table-types (EF Core _might_, but I doubt it'll work well...). good luck!

Comment: Another way is to use shadow and indexer properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties